# IOS Text color in PDF generation using core text framework not working

Tags: ios

I am using the following code to set the text color in Pdf generation. The code is working well ,the only problem is its not setting the text color.

```
   -(void)drawText:(NSString*)textToDraw inFrame:(CGRect)frameRect fontSize:
    (float)sizeofFont
   {
        NSLog(@"FONT SIZE %f",sizeofFont);
       int length=[textToDraw length];
        CFStringRef string = (__bridge CFStringRef) textToDraw;

       CFMutableAttributedStringRef currentText =
       CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
        CFAttributedStringReplaceString (currentText,CFRangeMake(0, 0), string);
        CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"UniversLTStd-BoldCn",
       sizeofFont, nil);
       CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(currentText,CFRangeMake(0,
       length),kCTFontAttributeName,font);

         CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(string);

       NSMutableAttributedString *string11 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                              initWithString:textToDraw];

       [string11 addAttribute:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName
                    value:(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor
                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [string11 length])];


     CTFramesetterRef framesetter = 
     CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText);

      CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
      CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, frameRect);
      CFRange currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);
     CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, 
      framePath, NULL);
     CGPathRelease(framePath);
     CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    
     CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
      CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, frameRect.origin.y*2);
     CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
      CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);
      CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
      CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, (-1)*frameRect.origin.y*2);
     CFRelease(frameRef);
    //CFRelease(currentText);
    CFRelease(framesetter);
    //CFRelease(stringRef);
}
```

but text color not changing.please help me how to do it?
I have different label and i have to set different color for different label .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this code:

```
CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(string);

   NSMutableAttributedString *string11 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                          initWithString:textToDraw];

   [string11 addAttribute:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName
                value:(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor
                range:NSMakeRange(0, [string11 length])];
```

with:

```
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(currentText,CFRangeMake(0, length),kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,[UIColor redColor].CGColor);
```